# CAShapeLayer 1px dash line

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to draw one pixel dash line but it always draws 2px line. Current solution:

```
let shapelayer = CAShapeLayer()
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

shapelayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
shapelayer.lineWidth = 1.0 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [1, 3]
shapelayer.path = path.CGPath
layer.addSublayer(shapelier)
```

Comment: You should always make sure your straight line lies on the centre line of a row of pixels – as the stroke saddles the line. You'll probably need to offset it by 0.5 points for a 1x or 3x display, or 0.25 points for a 2x display. Also setting the `contentsScale` is a good idea as matt points out ;)

Comment: Don't confuse pixels with points. You are asking for a 1 _point_ line and you are getting one. What you are getting is a 2 pixel rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the shape layer doesn't know you have a double-resolution screen, so it is drawing a 1 point line and it's being doubled to 2 pixels on the screen. You need to set the shape layer's `contentsScale` to your screen's display scale.

This issue arises only for layers you create yourself (like this one).

Comment: That's because you still have bad code remaining. Get rid of your `/ UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`. It's a red herring. Just draw a 1 point line in a correctly scaled layer and all will be well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the `contentsScale` only affect the size of the backing store of "logical" pixels that the device renders into – which is then up or down sampled as necessary to be displayed on the physical display? Therefore a 1pt line drawn into a 1x content scaled backing store will be up-sampled by 2x to be drawn on a 2x display, resulting in a 2px line. Similarly, a 1pt line drawn into a 2x backing store, then displayed straight onto a 2x display won't be sampled, resulting in a 2px line as well.

Comment: Therefore the `contentsScale` shouldn’t actually affect the displayed width of the line – only the quality (due to the sampling). I suspect the problem that OP’s having is that he’s trying to draw a single line dash segment with a 1px line width, but a 1pt line length. Therefore it would generate a 2x1 pixel segment for each dash on screen. Your solution will generate a 1x1 pt line segment, which will be 2x2 px on a 2x display.

Answer (score 2):

[@matt is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36939968/2976878) about changing the `contentsScale` of your layer – but that doesn't appear to be the problem you're facing here.

The `contentsScale` of a layer only affects the size of the backing store of "logical" pixels that the layer gets rendered into. However, in order to be displayed on a physical screen, this backing store will be down or up sampled in order to match the actual device's physical coordinate system.

If you draw a 1pt line in a 1x content scaled backing store of "logical" pixels – it will be represented as a 1px line in that coordinate system. However, it will have to be up-sampled in order to be displayed on a 2x display. This will effectively double it's width up to 2px (although the nature of up-sampling means you'll lose quality).

If you draw a 1pt line in a 2x content scaled backing store – it will be represented as a 2px line in that coordinate system. As the backing coordinate system & physical coordinate system match, it won't have to be sampled, and will be displayed as a 2px line on a 2x display.

Therefore the `contentsScale` doesn't actually affect the points to *physical* pixel ratio. It only affects quality (due to the sampling). You should therefore use the screen's scale for the `contentsScale` – as you should be matching the scale of the backing display of "logical" pixels with the physical scale of the device's display in order to avoid any loss in quality through sampling. However, using `1.0` for the line width will generate a 2px line on a 2x display, and a 3px line of a 3x display regardless of the `contentsScale`, as the line width is still defined in points. If you want your line width to be measured in pixels – you need to divide by the screen's scale.

---

The problem that you appear to have in your question is that you're drawing a line with a 1px line width, *but* you're setting 1pt for the line *length* (of the dash pattern). This will therefore lead to a line with each segment occupying 2x1 pixels on a 2x display.

The solution is to specify `1.0/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` for the line dash pattern *as well as* for the `lineWidth`. For example:

```
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [1.0/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, 3] // set whatever you want for the unstroked line dash length
shapelayer.lineWidth = 1.0/UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Furthermore, you'll need to offset your path by 0.5 points on a 1x or 3x display, and 0.25 points on a 2x display (or 0.75 points, depending on which pixel you want to clip the line with). You'll want to apply this offset to the line's y-coordinate if it's horizontal, or x-coordinate if it's vertical. This is because a line's stroke will 'saddle' the line – meaning it will be drawn either side of it. When you use an integral number for the the position of your line, you're drawing it on a pixel boundary.

While this doesn't usually have a big impact when using points – it matters when drawing at a pixel level. Offsetting the line will align it to the center of a pixel – meaning it's stroke will occupy a single pixel only. If a 1px line isn't correctly aligned to the pixel center, it will be shown with a reduced intensity across 2 pixels – creating an undesired effect.